# internationalized file not being picked up on iPhone

Tags: iphone, internationalization, plist

I have a .plist that I have had translated in my app. Originally, I had one .plist (icons.plist) at application root. I load the file as follows:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"icons" ofType:@"plist"]
```

After making the file localized, adding my specific language (de in this  case) I have checked to ensure icons.plist exists in English.lproj and de.lproj (it does).

I've always performed i18n this way and it has always worked prior to this, but now it doesn't seem to pick up the updated German file.

NSLogging the path it uses I find that it is still looking in "myApp.app/icons.plist" and not "myApp.app/de.lproj/icons.plist" as I would assume.

Have I missed an obvious step here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Delete your "build" directory (icons.plist might still exist)
- Remove the app from device, or do a full install by dragging the .app to the Organizer ("build and run/debug" apparently does an incremental install, which means it might not delete an existing icons.plist)

Comment: Was doing this on the simulator even after removing the build directory but manually deleting the .plist from myApp.app in iPhoneSimulator/3.2/Applications/0F1...  did the trick

Comment: Yup; that would be Xcode doing an "incremental install" but forgetting to delete files.